# Using %~dp0 to replace File Path with batch files

Tags: batch-file

I have been looking at this and I am really trying to find a way to remove a path

this is my path 
in the main folder `My Folder\Main Address\caller.bat` I have a batch that calls `address.bat`

Caller.bat

```
call "%~dp0\05) Address Finder\address.bat"
```

In the `05) Address Finder` I have my address.bat script and I have this

Address.bat

```
SET "sourcedir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\My Folder\Main Address\05) Address Finder"
SET "destdir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\My Folder\Main Address\06) Done"
```

I realized that this `%~dp0` works when it's in the main folder and reaches the other folders that are also in the main folder

But what I am trying to do to is setup the batch files that are in the inside of those other folders

Like this 
Address.bat

```
 SET "sourcedir=%~dp0\My Folder\Main Address\05) Address Finder"
 SET "destdir=%~dp0\My Folder\Main Address\06) Done"
```

or this 
Address.bat

```
SET "sourcedir=%~dp0\Main Address\05) Address Finder"
SET "destdir=%~dp0\Main Address\06) Done"
```

I'm trying to make it work on any computer, and in any folder, without me having to edit the address path

I know this works as long as I place the folder on the Desktop 
Address.bat

```
SET "sourcedir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\My Folder\Main Address\05) Address Finder"
SET "destdir=%UserProfile%\Desktop\My Folder\Main Address\06) Done"
```

I know that if `sourcedir` and `destdir` where in the same folder as address.bat then I could use this `%~dp0` but they are not

I found this, but don't know how to make it work I have tried a mixer of things

```
echo Full path and filename: %~f0
echo Drive: %~d0
echo Path: %~p0
echo Drive and path: %~dp0
echo Filename without extension: %~n0
echo Filename with    extension: %~nx0
echo Extension: %~x0
```

I tried my best to explain this

Comment: Well you're trying to use `%0` for something it's not intended. `%~dp0` will give you the drive and path to your script file and never anything else, under any circumstance. What exactly is your end-goal here?

Comment: Also the `%~dp` expansion, already carries a trailing backslash, so you shouldn't need to include one yourself, e.g. `%~dp0My Folder`, not `%~dp0\My Folder.`

Comment: Oh great I will remove the \, my end goal is to make all my script work in any folder, and in any computer I copy this to, I am not looking to making this a server script where other computers connect to it, all I want to do is copy my main folder and paste it anywhere I want,  if I want to run it from the Picture folder, or Document folder, Desktop etc.

Comment: @Compo - so I want to remove as much from the path as possible, now with my `address.bat` that is in a folder, and it needs to be able to find the folders that are sitting in the main folder `main folder\address folder\bat file` that is the location of this bat. and the way I have set up now it does read the folders in the main folder, but has to sit on desktop

Comment: Sounds increasingly like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). @JavierRivas, what exactly are you trying do? Forget about what you've tried, just tell us what is this script for? The one statement you've made "_what I am trying to do to is setup the batch files that are in the inside of those other folders_" isn't very clear.  Can you just read [ask] and tell us what problem you are trying to solve? It might also help if you posted an [mcve], instead of a bunch of random snippets.

Comment: @jwdonahue Well, I have many scripts, so my request is not only for 1 specific job, All my scripts work great, but the one thing I want I can't figure out, In many many scripts I have Sources and a directory and all my scripts are found inside sub folders, I have 1 batch that calls many scripts, but all my main folders have to sit on Desktop, to be able to run on any computer, if I put my main folder in Documents I would have to edit all my scripts with a new Source amd Directory, I am trying to eliminate having to edit source & directory in my scripts, everytime I place in a different folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding of your current structure:

```
%USERPROFILE%
└───Desktop
    └───My Folder
        └───Main Address
            │   caller.bat
            │
            ├───05) Address Finder
            │       address.bat
            │
            └───06) Done
```

…and what you're trying to do:

- To run `caller.bat` when `%UserProfile%\Desktop` is your Current Directory, you'd use its relative path `.\`:
  `Call ".\My Folder\Main Address\caller.bat"`
  Although the leading `.\` can be omitted:
  `Call "My Folder\Main Address\caller.bat"`
- To run `address.bat` from `caller.bat`, you'd  use its self path, `%~dp0`:

```batch-file
@Call "%~dp005) Address Finder\address.bat"
```

- And to use those paths within `address.bat`

```sh
@For %%G In ("%~dp0.") Do Set "sourcedir=%%~fG"
@For %%G In ("%~dp0..\06) Done") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"
```

Comment: Thank you, let me put this together will let you know how it goes

Comment: Thank you you saved me, I have updated all my scripts and all work great

Comment: Hey I do have 1 question, I'm adding this to a move.bat I'm moving txt files from folder A to the main folder, and I can't figure out how to move my files from Folder A to the main folder, `@For %%G In ("%~dp0..\Main Folder") Do Set "destdir=%%~fG"` like this `\Main Folder` it made my txt file disappear and placed this in my main folder `Main Folder` any ideas

Comment: i can make it work from folder to folder, but not folder to main

Comment: I'm sorry, @JavierRivas, but that's just too cryptic for me to understand. Up until this point, there has definitely not been a `folder A` or a `move.bat`. You're probably better off posting a new question, where you can provide the full structure all of the relevant batch file content, and their/its location.

Comment: Thank you sorry, remember I mentioned I have many scripts, well I have updated all my scripts, based on your answer, and I have 2 mover scripts,  but all I'm trying to do is `mov %source%\*.txt" "%destdir%` using your answer, `destdir = Main Folder` Once again Thank you, and if I have to ask another question that's fine,

Comment: I wanted to Thank you for the `Set Source` I have learned how it works and made it work on many scripts, I even made 3 lines, I placed the scripts in one folder and it calls out to 3 other folders, Thank you